# How would I program my bot to clear away placeholder writing?

Tags: html, vbscript, scripting, bots, notepad

I'm making a bot to log in to bing.com using plain old windows notepad, and so far, I have this:

```
set wb = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
wb.statusbar = false
wb.menubar = false
wb.toolbar = false
wb.visible = true

wb.navigate("https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1511575188&rver=6.7.6631.0&wp=MBI&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fsecure%2fPassport.aspx%3frequrl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252f%253fwlexpsignin%253d1&lc=1033&id=264960&CSRFToken=3f67b462-bf5b-4492-9925-e583298a3350&aadredir=1")

wscript.sleep(5000)

wb.document.all.item("i0116").value = "asdf1234@gmail.com"

wscript.sleep(100)
```

But, when the line that is supposed to type in my email "asdf1234@gmail.com" runs, a jumbled mess of stuff appears.

Originally, there are words in the box like "Email, phone number, or Skype" and you're supposed to click on it and type your email. But, when my bot does it, my email and the "placeholder text" mash together and produce random characters that are really weird.

I tried finding the id for the placeholder text so I can manipulate it by looking in inspect element, but I can't seem to do anything.

I'm really new to bot writing, and if anybody could help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried proceeding on with the login regardless of the garbled text? It may not actually matter if the "Email, phone number, or Skype" text appears on top of the username. It may not look pretty but it may work anyways as long as the correct username is in the .value of the text field.

Comment: @garbb Yeah, I've tried doing that, but I think Bing purposely does that so inexperienced people like me cant use bots :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to hide the hint text

```
wb.document.getElementsByClassName("phholder")(0).style.display = "none"
```

May I also suggest replacing `wscript.sleep(5000)` with

```
Do While true
    if wb.readystate = 4 then exit do
    wscript.sleep(100)
Loop
```

Which should just wait until the page is loaded.